# npm not compatible with node v12.5 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I tried updating to v12.5. I was using node version 8 before this. When I installed node v12.5 npm stopped working.
Whenever i try installing any package with npm. It shows this error.

[image]

I tried deleting node through different sources. But, it did not work.
I also tried reading different articles like these

https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-latest-node-js-and-nmp-packages-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04/

I almost tried all the sources available on web.

I tried

```
sudo apt purge node
sudo apt autoremove
```

and some similar commands. But, it did not work.
Whenever i type `node -v`. it still shows me `12.5`
and when i type `npm -v`. it shows me `5.5.1`.

How do i either remove node completely?
or
install specific version of node?
or upgrade npm to version `8.x`

How do I solve the problem?
I cannot even install anything, it shows this error even after installing some other packages.

how do i solve it?

EDIT:
I found the solution...
its basically using `nvm` to install different versions of node in your machine.
and setting default version for your machine using `nvm`

Comment: use `npm install npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version to latest

Comment: It shows the above error.. that i attached

Comment: The attached error is for installing npm packages but the above command is for upgrading the npm itself.

Comment: somewhere i am using npm to do that... thats why that error is popping up...
I tried the same command that you mentioned

Comment: Please share the error that you are getting while upgrading.